# Generate a Scratch Org Definition File from an Org Shape?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, org-shape

Is is possible to generate a scratch org definition file from an org shape?

Org Shape is still buggy. I'm running into this [known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwrWAAS/cant-create-a-digital-experience-cloud-site-using-org-shape) with Experience Cloud sites. It would be nice if I could use a tool to generate a scratch org definition file from my buggy org shape and possibly correct problems or make slight changes to the scratch org definition to work around the bugs.